# php filter by dropdown without submit button

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, form-submit

ive got the code below set up. but how do i filter the result without submit button and filtering the result based on dropdown value (id for user)?

```
form method="post" name="report_filter" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" >
select name="name" onchange="report_filter.submit();">
<option value="--">Filter by:</option>
<option value="1">Andi</option>
<option value="2">Katy</option>
<option value="3">Max</option>
<select>
PHP //
<? if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
    $mem->StaffTodayFilterSummary($_GET('value')); 
   else :
      $mem->StaffToday(); 
   endif;
?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change `name="report_filter"` to `id="report_filter"`.

Then change your `onchange` event to say `onchange="document.getElementById('report_filter').submit()"`

Here's the full code:

```
<form method="post" id="report_filter" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" >
    <select name="name" onchange="document.getElementById('report_filter').submit();">
        <option value="--">Filter by:</option>
        <option value="1">Andi</option>
        <option value="2">Katy</option>
        <option value="3">Max</option>
    <select>

    <?
    if(isset($_POST['name'])):
        $mem->StaffTodayFilterSummary($_POST['name']); 
    else :
      $mem->StaffToday(); 
    endif;
    ?>
</form>
```

I changed `isset()` to check `POST['name']` and set the filter summary to pass in `$_POST['name']` as well. I don't know where `$_GET('value')` was trying to get anything from but unless it's in the URL I don't see how it would work.

Comment: the form actually submitting.. but it just now showing the result. i guess its from the php side to get the dropdown value??

Comment: @boyee007 I don't see anything named "submit" in your form, so your line about isset($_POST['submit']) won't work. I think your logic may need to be changed. I will update my answer with corrected code.